# Magento 2 checkout form: how to apply custom template for field?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, template, forms

Currently I can redefine `ui/form/field` (not input!) use my theme,

but I need to set custom template for each field. I try to use code from [docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/howdoi/checkout/checkout_edit_form.html) with small fix.

```
<item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
        <!-- The name of the form the field belongs to -->
        <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                <!-- the field you are customizing -->
                <item name="firstname" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <!-- Assigning a new template -->
                        <!--
                        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">%Vendor_Module%/form/element/%your_template%</item>
                        -->
                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Checkout/form/field</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </item>
</item>
```

Templates (2 for testing...):

- `/app/code/Vendor/Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/form/field.html`;
- `/app/code/Vendor/Checkout/view/frontend/web/templates/form/field.html`.

This is not working. Why?

UPD: Fixed path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what the problem with this.

Go to `Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\AttributeMerger` line 173. You can see static value for template.

Details in the [my issue on github](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7993).

Answer (score 0):

**You have missing to declare frontend folder in your path name.**

Replace

```
app/code/Vendor/Checkout/view/web/template/form/field.html
```

With

```
app/code/Vendor/Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/form/field.html
```

Clear System cache and remove browser cache.

Comment: I made a mistake in path in question, I already had "frontend".